# Android - Write location to file

Tags: java, android, location

I am relatively new to dealing with the location on Android. So far I have seen the location used primarily in an Activity. I want to write out location to a file whenever there is an update or a certain about of time has passed. I have done this by following the Google code ([here](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-play-location)).

What I would like to know is if there is a way I can put this technique in a service background so it still performs when the app is closed, minimised, quit, phone sleeping, etc.

Is this possible and how can I achieve this? Thank you.